# Kotlin 2D array calculate mean by column

Tags: kotlin

I have a 2D array and I want to calculate the mean by column. For example:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] -> [2.5,3.5,4.5]
```

In python, I will simple do this

```
np.mean(array, axis=1)
```

How could I do it in Kotlin?

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin does not have 2D arrays, so it does not support operations for 2D arrays. Assuming we have an array of arrays and we know the size of each row is e.g. `3`, we can get averages using the following:

```kotlin
val arr = arrayOf(
    arrayOf(1, 2, 3),
    arrayOf(4, 5, 6),
)

val result = (0 until 3).map { col ->
    arr.map { it[col] }.average()
}

println(result) // [2.5, 3.5, 4.5]
```

If you often perform such operations then you can look at [Multik](https://github.com/Kotlin/multik) which is a multi-dimensional array implementation for Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all rows contain equal number of columns, you can do it this way:

```kotlin
val array = listOf(listOf(1, 2, 3), listOf(4, 5, 6))
val columns = array.first().size
val meanArray = List(columns) { col -> array.map { it[col] }.average() }
println(meanArray)
```

[try it yourself](https://pl.kotl.in/tVqaE_5HB)

Here `List(columns)` creates a list with number of elements equal to `columns`. Then for each column `col` `array.map { it[col] }` creates a list of elements in that column which is followed by a call to `average()` which just calculates the average of list elements.

Answer (score 0):

Simply get the first array from each array in the 2D array, since the 2D array is essencially an array of arrays

```
var median = 0
for(k in array.indices) {
    median += array[k][0]
}
median /= array.indices
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val list = arrayOf(arrayOf(1, 2, 3), arrayOf(4, 5, 6))

val result = list.first().mapIndexed { 
  index, _ -> list.sumOf { it[index] }.div(list.size.toDouble())
}

println(result)   // [2.5, 3.5, 4.5]
```

This would also work for any number of sub-arrays:

```
val list = arrayOf(arrayOf(1, 2, 3), arrayOf(4, 5, 6), arrayOf(7, 8, 9))
...
println(result)   // [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
```